# Saving complex objects to database using RxJava

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, rx-java

I have an application that makes requests to a 3rd party API and needs to save most of that data to a local Sqlite database (where local primary keys are autoincremented).

Those requests return a JSON response that often contains many nested objects, that I need to map and save and then link that record back to the original parent object *ObjectA in this case*.

```
{
 "ObjectAList": [
   {
    "somefield1": "someValue1",
    "someField2": "someValue2",
    "nestedObjectB": {
        "nestedField": "nestedValue"
     },
     "nestedObjectCArray": [
      {
       "nestedArrayField": "nestedArrayValue"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
 }
```

The app is powered by RxJava; for which I'm fairly new to. (both the networking and persistence via StorIO are reactive). I am able to set up methods to save in bulk the parent *ObjectA* and that works fine. However I run in to issues as I start to iterate though each of those objects using Observable.from and subsequently saving the nested child objects, collecting those records, and updating the foreign keys in their respective parent items (with usage of Observable.zip for multiple children). Often the function would be executed (according to my logs anyway), but somehow the results don't get submitted back through the rest of the chain, so I'm not sure if something went wrong or if there's an issue with my approach/implementation.

Any help or pointers on how to do this would be appreciated!

**Edit some sample psudeo-code added**

```
/*this flatmap is attached to a network request that returns 
the previously defined JSON response*/

.flatMap(new Func1<List<ObjectAResponse>, Observable<List<ObjectAResponse>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<ObjectAResponse>> call(final List<ObjectAResponse> objectAResponse) {

            return saveObjectAListToDb(someOtherKey, objectAJsonResponses)                            
            .map(new Func1<PutResults<ObjectAEntity>, List<ObjectAResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ObjectAResponse> call(PutResults<ObjectAEntity> putResults) {
                //Returning the original response to get the nested values
                return objectAResponse;
            }
        });
    }
})
.flatMap(new Func1<List<ObjectAResponse>, Observable<ObjectAResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ObjectAResponse> call(List<ObjectAResponse> objectAResponse) {
                //Start emitting individual 'ObjectA' items to process its child items
                return Observable.from(objectAResponse);
            }
        })
.flatMap(new Func1<ObjectAResponse, Observable<ObjectAEntity>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ObjectAEntity> call(ObjectAResponse objectAResponse) {
                    /*Saving the individual nested objects in separate functions that return an observable that contains
                    * the resultant entity to be updated in to the main ObjectA entity
                    * (in reality there could be more nested child objects to save in parallel)
                    */
                    return Observable.zip(saveEpic(objectAResponse.nestedObjectB), saveUser(objectAResponse.nestedObjectCArray), 
                        new Func2<ObjectBEntity, ObjectCEntity, ObjectAEntity>() {

                        @Override
                        public Object call(ObjectBEntity objectBEntity, ObjectCEntity objectCEntity) {
                            //Function that updates the initial object with the new entities
                            return updateObjectA(objectAResponse.id, objectBEntity, objectCEntity);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
.collect(new Func0<List<ObjectAEntity>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ObjectAEntity> call() {
                    return new ArrayList<ObjectAEntity>();
                }
            },
            new Action2<List<ObjectAEntity>, ObjectAEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<ObjectAEntity> objectAEntityList, ObjectAEntity o) {
                    //Collect the resultant updated entities and return the list
                    objectAEntityList.add(o);
                }
            });
```

Comment: without code, it's hard to tell...

Comment: I think that for that you could take a look at REALM they support rx and I'm using it and works just fine.

Comment: @njzk2 ill update with some sample code to help clarify